# Проблема с rigidbody и animator

Tags: unity3d

Работаю с туториалом, возникла проблема, которую я не могу понять. Есть объект, к которому прикручен animator с анимацией и rigidbody. При включенном аниматоре, на объект не действует гравитация (он не падает вниз, при этом работает анимация), при выключенном аниматоре - все работает, объект падает. С чем связано такое поведение? В туториале есть объяснение на английском, но я его не понял.
[Ссылка](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/the-player-character-part-1?language=en&projectId=5caf65ddedbc2a08d53c7acb#5caf91ebedbc2a0f5d7f7438) на туториал, пункты 12-13.

Answer (score 0):

Вы проверили:

- RigidBody -  Dynamic?
- RigidBody - Gravity scale = 1 (или любому другому значению, не равному 0)?